# Validate hexadecimal string using regular expression

Tags: regex

I am validating a string whether it is hexadecimal or not using regular expression.

The expression I used is `^[A-Fa-f0-9]$`. When I using this, the string `AABB10` is recognized as a valid hexadecimal, but the string `10AABB` is recognized as invalid.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Should it be `^[A-Fa-f0-9]+$` in the first place?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You most likely need a `+`, so `regex = '^[a-fA-F0-9]+$'`. However, I'd be careful to (perhaps) think about such things as an optional `0x` at the beginning of the string, which would make it `^(0x|0X)?[a-fA-F0-9]+$'`.

Comment: `^(0x|0X)*` should be `(0[xX])?` otherwise it also matches against "0x0x0x0x1234abcd" which is not a standard hex string. See my ans

Comment: Maybe it would be better to ensure your hex string is formatted as a hexadecimal string to your context, such as css colors with 6 digits, and assert a number of characters rather then an unlimited number of characters. E.g. `^(0[xX]){1}[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}$ | ^#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}$`

Answer (score 11):

`^[A-Fa-f0-9]+$`

should work, `+` matches `1` or more chars.

Using Python:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: re.match?
Type:       function
Base Class: <type 'function'>
String Form:<function match at 0x01D9DCF0>
Namespace:  Interactive
File:       python27\lib\re.py
Definition: re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)
Docstring:
Try to apply the pattern at the start of the string, returning
a match object, or None if no match was found.

In [3]: re.match(r"^[A-Fa-f0-9]+$", "AABB10")
Out[3]: <_sre.SRE_Match at 0x3734c98>

In [4]: re.match(r"^[A-Fa-f0-9]+$", "10AABB")
Out[4]: <_sre.SRE_Match at 0x3734d08>
```

Ideally You might want something like `^(0[xX])?[A-Fa-f0-9]+$` so you can match against strings with the common `0x` formatting like `0x1A2B3C4D`

```
In [5]: re.match(r"^(0[xX])?[A-Fa-f0-9]+$", "0x1A2B3C4D")
Out[5]: <_sre.SRE_Match at 0x373c2e0>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you forget the '+'? Trying "^[A-Fa-f0-9]+$"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process a hex dump such as,

```
0x01 0x02 0x03 0xff 0xFF
```

you may use split string using `str.Text.Split(' ');` to obtain a list, then you may iterate over the list using following pattern

```
^(0[x]){1}[a-fA-F0-9]{2}$
```